# XMLSyntaxError Start tag expected, '<' not found

Tags: xml, django, lxml

In Django i build a script that create xml object to make xml request. Here is my code:

```
my_xml = etree.XML('''\"<?xml version="1.0"? encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE peticion SYSTEM "http://example.com"> ]><request></request>"''')
my_xml_doc = etree.ElementTree(my_xml)
my_tipe = etree.SubElement(my_xml, "element")
my_tipe.text = 'Element'
my_xml_serialize = etree.parse(my_xml)
my_request = urllib2.Request(url, my_xml_serialize)
```

But django throws an error

```
XMLSyntaxError Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: The single quotes and escape chars before the prolog look suspect to me. I'd take another look at the example for Doc Type here: http://lxml.de/1.3/parsing.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Python is doing string concatenation behind the scenes](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation). Observe:

```
> "x"'f'=='xf'
True
```

So your string:

```
'''\"<?xml version="1.0"? encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE peticion SYSTEM "http://example.com"> ]><request></request>"'''
```

is actually computed as:

```
''+'\"<?xml version="1.0"? encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE peticion SYSTEM "http://example.com"> ]><request></request>"'+''
```

which is:

```
'\"<?xml version="1.0"? encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE peticion SYSTEM "http://example.com"> ]><request></request>"'
```

the start of that string is a literal double quoate (`"`). This isn't valid in XML outside of angle brackets. Hence the error.

Change it to the following and it should work fine:

```
'<?xml version="1.0"? encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE peticion SYSTEM "http://example.com"> ]><request></request>'
```

---

edit: Fine was an overstatement, the original issue was string concatenation. However, after a brief and generous check you have numerous issues in your actual XML document, including syntax errors, an incorrectly specified DOCTYPE and a document that doesn't actually conform to that DOCTYPE.

Trimming the document all the way back to:

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><request></request>'
```

will allow the code to run, but any help on getting the DOCTYPE to work is definitely another question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i did like you said and now i have another error `XMLSyntaxError Blank needed here, line 1, column 19`

Comment: @ZagorodniyOlexiy I've added some more details.

Comment: I'm sorry for more question to you. I find the bug, thank you!